# How to customize the text in a default About window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, about-box

I have a Cocoa app and I want to use the default About window like this:

[image]

How can I change the text? ex:

> Engineering:
>       Some people (I want to change this text to the real developer)

Can it be configured somewhere in the info.plist file? I can't find any related key after reading the Apple document about info.plist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in the `en.lproj` folder for a file called "Credits.rtf"

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Credits.rtf file in most editors. Xcode is a bit limited, compared to even TextEdit.